# Write html inside value of an input text correctly with Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working in a project and can't find the fix for this:

```
$("#description").attr("value", '<?php echo htmlentities($version["Description"], ENT_NOQUOTES);?>');
```

The value of `$version["Description"]` is `Genérica` and in the value of the input text is`Gen & eacute ; rica`.

I tried:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;
```

as well as different encodings on `htmlentities` like iso or utf-8.

I think that `.html()` of jquery can help but how do I use it on attr for value?

Comment: _The value of $version["Description"] is "Genérica" and in the value of the input text show "Genérica"._ Wherein lies the problem? Those strings are identical.

Comment: The input text show gen &eacu te; rica, together...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [jQuery val function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to post something in an input (or textarea).

What you really want is to [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) (transfers `&eacute;` in é) instead of [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) (é in `&eacute;`).

Comment: getting "Gen & eacute ; rica" with val too